# Visual studio Code error, setting the 'outFiles' might heIp

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, ide

So, I worked with VSC earlier, no problem whatsoever. Then it didn't work anymore, something about node not being found in PATH

Downloaded Node, and now it sais

|-------------------------------------------------------------------|

| (X)..Cannot launch program...................................|

| ........'c:\users...\decimal_converter.py';..................|

| ........setting the 'outFiles' attribute might................|

|..................................|Open launch.json| |cancel|...|

|-------------------------------------------------------------------|

Now, since it originally worked I am confused why it doesn't anymore: ATOM has no problem running my code. What could actually cause that. I will for the time being continue to use Atom, I am currently trying both to see what fits me. Would be cool if VSC stopped breaking.

I researched online, but solutions are not working and far between.

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so, wow. I fixed it but I don't know if that's fixing the problem or the symptom.

For further reference, if anyone has this problem:

I don't know why, but it tried to run the `launch.jsn`. I tried around, nothing worked. So, I just deleted everything.

It worked again. Until it didn't. This time I *only* deleted 'launch,jsn' and it works again. My unprofessional SUSPISSION is that it hates me, or that it tries to run 'launch.jsn'. Once it was deleted it worked again.

Is it smart to delete it? IDK, but it worked.